# Why and how is state being set this way inside `getDerivedStateFromError`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning about ErrorBoundaries in React and was wondering why and how in the `getDerivedStateFromError` method, is state being set this way?

```
// REACT
import React from 'react';

export class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {

  state = {
    isThereError: false
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    return {
      isThereError: true 
    };
  }

  // ...

};
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
// REACT
import React from 'react';

export class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {

  state = {
    isThereError: false
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    
    this.setState({ isThereError: true })

  }

  // ...

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

State isn't being set in the method itself.  But [by convention](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromerror) the framework *expects* that method to return an updated state object.  The framework then *internally* uses that result to update state:

> This lifecycle is invoked after an error has been thrown by a descendant component. It receives the error that was thrown as a parameter **and should return a value to update state**.

So when implementing `getDerivedStateFromError` in your component you don't need to worry about updating state within that method.  Just return the new state.